# Use REPLACE on column data type TEXT SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I try use this code to resolve acute accent on column type text:

```sql
UPDATE [AcuerdateWEB].[dbo].[Actividad]
SET Descripcion = REPLACE(CAST(Descripcion AS nvarchar(max)), 'ó', '&oacute')
WHERE Descripcion like '%&oacute%'
```

The problem is that the column's datatype is `text` and can not be replaced; but when I use the code above appears that the query was successfully and show the total of rows affected

Comment: Why are you still using TEXT? It's been deprecated for 10 years...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it TEXT or NTEXT? You are mixing types in the REPLACE.

The reason it completes without error but does not do anything is that you are asking it to replace any `ó` with `&oacute`, and only in records that have `&oacute`.

The way this is currently written, it is ambiguous as to which one you want to replace with the other, so I will show both.

If you want to replace `ó` with `&oacute`:

```sql
UPDATE [AcuerdateWEB].[dbo].[Actividad]
SET Descripcion = REPLACE(CAST(Descripcion AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'ó', '&oacute')
WHERE Descripcion like '%ó%';
```

If you want to replace `&oacute` with `ó`:

```sql
UPDATE [AcuerdateWEB].[dbo].[Actividad]
SET Descripcion = REPLACE(CAST(Descripcion AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '&oacute', 'ó')
WHERE Descripcion like '%&oacute%';
```

Also, if the data type is really NTEXT, just change the `VARCHAR(MAX)` to be `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and prefixed the 3 string literals with `N`, as in:

```sql
UPDATE [AcuerdateWEB].[dbo].[Actividad]
SET Descripcion = REPLACE(CAST(Descripcion AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), N'ó', N'&oacute')
WHERE Descripcion like N'%ó%';
```

Comment: thank you, you're right,I set the strings in the wrong parameter.